# Click the checkbox using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to click the checkbox using Selenium Python.

.html before click checkbox:

```
<section class="content__supFooter ng-star-inserted">
   <p-checkbox binary="false" name="agreement" class="ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid">
     <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
       <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
          <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable"></span>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

.html after click checkbox:

```
<section class="content__supFooter ng-star-inserted">
       <p-checkbox binary="false" name="agreement" class="ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid">
         <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
           <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
               <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
          <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable pi pi-check"></span>
           </div>
         </div>
     </section>
```

I tried:

1:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable")
# element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('section')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

2:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/elm-app/elm-covid-vaccine-registration/div/main/content/section/elm-cvr-register-visitor/div/section[2]/p-checkbox/div/div[1]/input').click()
```

But cant detect the checkbox, any kind of help please?

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable")
```

this is wrong, instead use `css` with `find_element`.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.ui-chkbox-icon.ui-clickable")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

should work for you.